# Get vCard from Contactdata Intent - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, vcf-vcard

lets be quick and precise.
I am searching for a way getting a vCard string from a contact I selected and that was delivered via an intent to my application.

First I made an intent to open the phonebook and select a contact as you can see in this code,

```
mContext.startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE), 1);
```

after selecting a contact the result is deleivered in an intent that is caught here

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {   // RQS_PICK_CONTACT = 1
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                vCard = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                System.out.println(vCard);
            }
        }
    }
```

In this example I just get the number saved for this contact.
But I am aiming to claim the entire details in one vCard string, or another format that allows me to convert it to vCard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could manage to claim the vCard with this simple line

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
```

Here is the full code to get a vCard as String

```
public string vCard(Intent data){
Uri contactData = data.getData();

                    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
                    AssetFileDescriptor fd;
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String nummer  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    try {
                        fd = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
                        FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
                        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
                        fis.read(buf);
                        return new String(buf); //vCard from buffer
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load Contact: " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
return null; 
}
```

Comment: how is the method vCard(Intent data) called? lets say I want to call from onCreate() method. And managedQuery(...) looks depricated in API 17. Any alternatives to this as well?

Comment: I catch it as ActivityResult
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == 1) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
Uri contactData = data.getData();
[...]
}}}

Comment: Here is also an example to initiate the selection for a contact which is returned to the activity as an intent in onActivityResult
---
mContext.startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE), 1);